# Javascript Regular expression help needed example text and goal stated

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm storing an ugly value in a field within a table.

string1:
s:90:"a:2:{s:8:"latitude";s:18:"37.453896007474455";s:9:"longitude";s:19:"-122.28786132646483";}";

string2:
s:90:"a:2:{s:8:"latitude";s:18:"1.03923923929";s:9:"longitude";s:19:"-10.28786132646483";}";

string3:
s:90:"a:2:{s:8:"latitude";s:18:"3.455";s:9:"longitude";s:19:"-140.28786132646483";}";

What regex would match all of 37.453896007474455, 1.03923923929, 3.455

What regex would match all of -122.28786132646483, -10.28786132646483, -140.28786132646483

Thank you

In either case, a minus sign may appear before the digits before the period.

Comment: Where is  the data coming from? Any chance you could get a JSON instead, or do they offer a parser library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `(-?\d+(?:.\d+)?)` to match an optional minus (`-?`), followed by at least one number `\d+`, followed `(?:\.\d+)?`, which creates an optional `?` non capturing group `?:` for a decimal `\.`, followed by at least one number `\d+`.

Assuming the `string` always starts with `s:90:"a:2:{s:8:"latitude";s:18:"`, to get the first set of numbers, you could use:

```
s:90:"a:2:{s:8:"latitude";s:18:"(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
```

Assuming the first set of numbers is always followed by `";s:9:"longitude";s:19:"`, to get the second set of numbers, you could use:

```
";s:9:"longitude";s:19:"(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
```